# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, fragment

I found similar topics in stackoverflow but it didn't help for me.
I am showing google map using fragment and it crashes after get another fragment and come back.
In other words, google map shows only once and crashes.
Here are the codes.

```
public class MapTabMainFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = null;
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_main, container,
                    false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initComponents(view);
        initValues();
        initListeners();

        return view;
    }

    public void initComponents(View view) {
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    }

    public void initValues() {
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(re);
    }

    public void initListeners() {

    }
}

 public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public BottomTabActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActivity = (BottomTabActivity) this.getActivity();
    }

    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return false;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }
}
```

when I try to catch the exception, it is

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/data_listview_margin_top" >

        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/data_listview_margin_bottom"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        <!--class="com.cyrilmottier.polaris2.maps.SupportMapFragment"  -->

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9766031373541061/3761995838"
            app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The error is in your XML file. Can you please post it?

Comment: @Szymon - I've posted XML file

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have nested fragments in XML. You should do it in code.
The best way is to create a FrameLayout, and replace it with your fragment at run-time.

Suppose the XML is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/inquiryLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".InquiryFragment" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now the code is simple:

```
public class InquiryFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inquiry_fragment, container, false);

        Plan1Fragment frag = new Plan1Fragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentFrame, frag).commit();

        return v;
    }

}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it myself after research on stackoverflow.
It's something related with nested fragment issues.
I removed map fragment in xml and placed frame for it and then add fragment programmatically.
it works like a charm.
Thanks for your all efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way

public class MapTabMainFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map_main);
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(re);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the Activity before it's actually created in your BaseFragment class...

```
mActivity = (BottomTabActivity) this.getActivity();
```

Instead, override the "onActivityCreated" method and do it there...

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mActivity = (BottomTabActivity) this.getActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the  element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

->this solves mine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the Linear Layout tag, put it in  `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` tag. as shown below:

```html
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9766031373541061/3761995838"
        app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

**For further assistance visit this [Link](http://www.techcorns.com/2015/05/23/make-money-android-app-ads/)**