# Error inflating class fragment when Run app second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I tried following solutions no one worked for me.

1) [When inflating fragment which was previously inflated app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449124/when-inflating-fragment-which-was-previously-inflated-app-crashes)

2) [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106654/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-20-error-inflating-class-f) there are no nested fragments I think

I am getting crash `Error inflating class fragment` when I run app after finishing 1st time.

When Open App first time everything is fine. When open app for second time crash. and when open 3rd time then app working fine. and so on.

Following is the code of my `Activity` having fragments

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.taazi.Activities.MainActivity" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
    -->
    <!--
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_left"
        android:name="com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_right"
        android:name="com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentRight"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Code of main `Activity`

```
package com.taazi.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft;
import com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentRight;
import com.taazi.Fragments.PlaceholderFragment;
import com.taazi.Fragments.PlayerFragment;
import com.taazi.android.R;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.NavigationDrawerCallbacksLeft,NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.NavigationDrawerCallbacksRight{

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft;
    private NavigationDrawerFragmentRight mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    public static Context context;
    public static ActionBar actionBar;
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft = (NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer_left);
        mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight = (NavigationDrawerFragmentRight) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer_right);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer_left,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer_right,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }


    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
    }
    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_right_drawer:
            toggleRightDrawer();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggleLeftDrawer();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static void toggleLeftDrawer(){
        if(NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        if(NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else{
            NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }

    public static void toggleRightDrawer(){
        if(NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)){
            NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        if(NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }else{
            NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelectedRight(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlayerFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelectedLeft(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

}
```

Log.

```
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.taazi.android/com.taazi.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.taazi.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    ... 11 more
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:910)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1111)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.java:159)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.java:61)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-28 11:28:58.417: E/AndroidRuntime(22774):    ... 24 more
```

Code of `NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.java`

```
package com.taazi.Fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.taazi.android.R;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacksLeft mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;

    public NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelectedLeft(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacksLeft) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacksLeft {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelectedLeft(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line 159 in `NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.java` ?

Comment: It is `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);`. NullPointerException is because of inflating error.

Comment: where is it initialized mDrawerLayout?

Comment: It is in `setUp` function. I updated question with code of `NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.java` file.

Comment: where is `setup` called. `mDrawerLayout` is null

Comment: @Raghunandan in `MainActivity's` `onCreate` function. Code of `MainActivity` is in Question.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes `mDrawerLayout` is null because Error occur before setup function called in `MainActivity's` `onCreate` function.

Comment: you are calling the method too soon. `mDrawerLayout` is null. re-think your design

Comment: When I run app 1st time is works without problem. I am facing problem when I open it second time.

Comment: check if `getActivity()` returns null. You will know yourself. good luck

Comment: On running second time an exception occur inside `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` :/

Comment: When I used `System.exit(0);` in `finish()` function It works fine. I think there is some cleaning problem. Can some one tell me which things I have to clean in `finish()` function?

Comment: `System.exit(0)` itself is wrong. I can't comment any further. A quick google search should give you a clue

Comment: I just tried `System.exit(0);` to confirm there is some cleaning problem. Thanks for your help @Raghunandan

Comment: Problem solved by adding this line in `finish()` `NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.mDrawerLayout = null;` because `mDrawerLayout` was static.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to replace this line :

```
   `android:name="com.taazi.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragmentLeft"`
```

With

```
class = "com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove static from drawer layout ... i had same issue ..

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for your answer. If you could please edit it and explain what the code you're suggesting does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.